# Generate code for specific record instead of all records

Tags: sql, asp.net, .net, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I have code to generate a unique code for a filed in a SQL Server 2017 table. The entire code block works great without any issues. Due to user requirements I have to do this differently now. As you can see from my code it will generate a code for each row of data and set all rows 'Valid' filed to valid. What I absolutely have to do is generate the code for a specific record. And specifically for the most recently updated record. I totally understand how to get the most recently updated records and how to apply IDENT_CURRENT, @@IDENTITY, and SCOPE_IDENTITY but I wondered if there is something similar for recently Updated records. When I say updated record an Approver in Finance will change the Finance_Approval field status 'approved'. That specific record that was just changed to 'approved' is the one I want to generate my code againt. This code:
UPDATE Req_submitted
Set approved_code =
(SELECT FLOOR(RAND()*(525885-15+9)+16458)),
Valid = 'valid'

Below is all of code for the Trigger. I'm hoping this is a challenge someone wants to take on as my SQL has hit a wall on this one but the feature is very important.

```
  ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Approve_request_trig]
```

ON  [dbo].[Req_submitted]
AFTER update
AS
Begin
declare
@req_submitted_key           int,
@Submitted_to_finance_approver_email     varchar(50),
@approved_denied      varchar(50),
@approved_finance  varchar(50)

```
  select @req_submitted_key = s.req_submitted_key,
         @Submitted_to_finance_approver_email = s.Submitted_to_finance_approver_email,
         @approved_denied  = s.approved_denied,
         @approved_finance = s.approved_finance
         
  from inserted s;

  
      if update(approved_finance)
  
UPDATE Req_submitted
       Set approved_code =
       (SELECT FLOOR(RAND()*(525885-15+9)+16458)),
       Valid = 'valid'
      ;
```

End

Comment: Have you looked at and rejected [Sequence Numbers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sequence-numbers/sequence-numbers?view=sql-server-ver15)? Do you really want to `update `all rows, not just those that have been updated, e.g. by referencing [`inserted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15)? Under what conditions would `@@Identity` be useful?

Comment: Hello there. I actually want to generate a numeric value only the specific row that has a changed value in the 'approved_finance' field. I should have been more clear. My apologies. I absolutely DO NOT want to generate values for all rows.

Comment: Also, I know this is most likely incorrect [from inserted s;] so I tried changing it to [from updated s;] but I immediately get a Syntax error.

Comment: Something like `update Reqs set Approved_Code = <NumberCalculation>, Valid = 'valid' from Req_Submitted as Reqs inner join Inserted as I on I.IdColumn = Reqs.IdColumn;` would be typical. (Assuming that there is an `IdColumn` that uniquely idenitifes each row.) You emphasize needing a "unique" code, but you use `Rand()`. How often can you flip a coin before getting a duplicate result? Your `select` will behave badly when multiple rows have been updated. If only a single row can be updated at a time then your trigger should check that and `throw` an exception is multiple rows are changed.

Comment: I'll change out the RAND generator and try the join. And yes, the unique id column is Req_submitted. It is also the primary key.